# Do bound functions support proper tail calls in ES6?

Tags: ecmascript-6, language-lawyer, tail-call-optimization, tail-call

In the ECMAScript 2015 Language Specification, the definitions of [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-function.prototype.apply) and [`Function.prototype.call`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-function.prototype.call) both include "Perform PrepareForTailCall()" as one of their steps, so we know that these functions support proper tail calls (i.e., tail call optimisation).

The definition of [[[Call]] on bound function objects](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-bound-function-exotic-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist), however, omits PrepareForTailCall().  Does this mean that bound functions do not support proper tail calls, and that a bound function calling itself recursively could blow up the stack?

Comment: N.B. I am aware that few JS interpreters actually support proper tail calls; this is a question about the spec, not about actual implementation.

Comment: No, when [[Call]] is called on the bound function, the prepareForTailCall has already been done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The definition of `[[Call]]` on bound function objects omits `PrepareForTailCall()`. Does this mean that bound functions do not support proper tail calls, and that a bound function calling itself recursively could blow up the stack?

No. The `PrepareForTailCall` happens in [`EvaluateDirectCall` during the evaluation of the call expression](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-evaluatedirectcall), where it checks whether that expression is in a tail position. When the tail call is prepared, the current running execution context is dropped, before the function is [called](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-call), dispatching on the respective `[[Call]]` internal method. The new running execution context is set up in [`PrepareForOrdinaryCall`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-prepareforordinarycall) from the [`[[Call]]` method of user-defined functions](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ecmascript-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist). The [`[[Call]]` method of bound functions](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-bound-function-exotic-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist) just introduces an extra level of indirection before that happens.

> In the ECMAScript 2015 Language Specification, the definitions of `Function.prototype.apply` and `Function.prototype.call` both include "*Perform `PrepareForTailCall()`*" as one of their steps, so we know that these functions support proper tail calls.

Yes, this is necessary because the [`[[Call]]` method of built-in functions](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-built-in-function-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist) sets up a new running execution context (for the "implementation-defined steps"). It is this "builtin context" that the `PrepareForTailCall` will drop before the actual function is called.

The `call` and `apply` methods are functions calling functions, and when they are called there are two calls on the stack that need to be tail-call-optimised. (Contrast this to - for example - `Array.prototype.map`, which also calls other functions, but here the `map` execution context stays on the call stack. In `call` and `apply`, the `Call()` is indeed in a tail position of the algorithm).

Answer (score 1):

See §12.3.4.1 ([Runtime Semantics: Evaluation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-function-calls-runtime-semantics-evaluation)). First, we do `IsInTailPosition`, then we do `EvaluateDirectCall` -- the result of which is `F.[[Call]]`. In other words, by the time we make the actual call, we already know whether or not we're in a tail position.

However, as you mention, JS is [not tail-optimized on any browser](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/), except Safari.